# Repeatedly extract a line between two delimiters in a text file, Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file in the following format:

```
DELIMITER1
extract me
extract me
extract me
DELIMITER2
```

I'd like to extract every block of `extract me`s between DELIMITER1 and DELIMITER2 in the .txt file

This is my current, non-performing code:

```
import re
def GetTheSentences(file):
     fileContents =  open(file)
     start_rx = re.compile('DELIMITER')
     end_rx = re.compile('DELIMITER2')

     line_iterator = iter(fileContents)
     start = False
     for line in line_iterator:
           if re.findall(start_rx, line):

                start = True
                break
      while start:
           next_line = next(line_iterator)
           if re.findall(end_rx, next_line):
                break

           print next_line

           continue
      line_iterator.next()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can simplify this to one regular expression using `re.S`, the [DOTALL flag](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL).

```
import re
def GetTheSentences(infile):
     with open(infile) as fp:
         for result in re.findall('DELIMITER1(.*?)DELIMITER2', fp.read(), re.S):
             print result
# extract me
# extract me
# extract me
```

This also makes use of the non-greedy operator `.*?`, so multiple non-overlapping blocks of DELIMITER1-DELIMITER2 pairs will all be found.

Comment: tip: use this with a memory-mapped file object (via the `mmap` module) if your file is too large to read in all at once.

Comment: @Brent Tried this out and it functions nicely...Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it is the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

If the delimiters are within a line:

```
def get_sentences(filename):
    with open(filename) as file_contents:
        d1, d2 = '.', ',' # just example delimiters
        for line in file_contents:
            i1, i2 = line.find(d1), line.find(d2)
            if -1 < i1 < i2:
                yield line[i1+1:i2]


sentences = list(get_sentences('path/to/my/file'))
```

If they are on their own lines:

```
def get_sentences(filename):
    with open(filename) as file_contents:
        d1, d2 = '.', ',' # just example delimiters
        results = []
        for line in file_contents:
            if d1 in line:
                results = []
            elif d2 in line:
                yield results
            else:
                results.append(line)

sentences = list(get_sentences('path/to/my/file'))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in get_sentences
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'results' referenced before assignment

Comment: @amadain I added a line to initialize results, but looking at this I'm not sure it's correct anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
import re
def GetTheSentences(file):
    start_rx = re.compile('DELIMITER')
    end_rx = re.compile('DELIMITER2')

    start = False
    output = []
    with open(file, 'rb') as datafile:
         for line in datafile.readlines():
             if re.match(start_rx, line):
                 start = True
             elif re.match(end_rx, line):
                 start = False
             if start:
                  output.append(line)
    return output
```

Your previous version looks like it's supposed to be an iterator function. Do you want your output returned one item at a time? That's slightly different.

Comment: There is no need to read the whole file into memory. You also don't need regular expressions if it's something as simple as finding specific substring in a line.

Comment: @agf Of course not, but his simplistic example may not exactly correspond with his data. I've done a very similar thing over a postscript file, and I absolutely had to have regular expressions for my start and end points.

Comment: @Renklauf no problem, that's what we're here for. You may want to pick one as the answer though...

Answer (score 0):

This is a good job for List comprehensions, no regex required. First list comp scrubs the typical `\n` in the text line list found when opening txt file. Second list comp just uses `in` operator to identify sequence patterns to filter.

```
def extract_lines(file):
    scrubbed = [x.strip('\n') for x in open(file, 'r')]
    return [x for x in scrubbed if x not in ('DELIMITER1','DELIMITER2')]
```

Comment: This returns the entire file except those two lines, not the lines between the delimiters.