# How to extract information between two unique words in a large text file

Tags: python, parsing, search, text, batch-file

I have about 150 text files filled with character information. Each file contains two unique words ()alpha and bravo and i want to extract the text between these unique words and write it to a different file.

Manually i can CTRL+F for the two words and copy the text between, i just want to know how to do this using a program (preferably Python) for many files.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) for that.

```
>>> st = "alpha here is my text bravo"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'alpha(.*?)bravo',st)
[' here is my text ']
```

My test.txt file

```
alpha here is my line
yipee
bravo
```

Now using [open](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to read the file and than applying `regular expressions`.

```
>>> f = open('test.txt','r')
>>> data = f.read()
>>> x = re.findall(r'alpha(.*?)bravo',data,re.DOTALL)
>>> x
[' here is my line\nyipee\n']
>>> "".join(x).replace('\n',' ')
' here is my line yipee '
>>>
```

Comment: @JohnMachin: fixed the `x` thing.

Comment: ``` raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat```

Answer (score 12):

```
a = 'alpha'
b = 'bravo'
text = 'from alpha all the way to bravo and beyond.'

text.split(a)[-1].split(b)[0]
# ' all the way to '
```

Comment: You can help split by adding a count of 1, so it will stop looking for additional instances to split on:  `text.split(a,1)`

Answer (score 7):

`str.find` and its sibling `rfind` have `start` and `end` args.

```
alpha = 'qawsed'
bravo = 'azsxdc'
startpos = text.find(alpha) + len(alpha)
endpos = text.find(bravo, startpos)
do_something_with(text[startpos:endpos]
```

This is the fastest way if the contained text is short and near the front.

If the contained text is relatively large, use:

```
startpos = text.find(alpha) + len(alpha)
endpos = text.rfind(bravo)
```

If the contained text is short and near the end, use:

```
endpos = text.rfind(bravo)
startpos = text.rfind(alpha, 0, endpos - len(alpha)) + len(alpha)
```

The first method is in any case better than the naive method of starting the second search from the start of the text; use it if your contained text has no dominant pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using regular expression use Python `string.find` method.

```
>>>> unique_word_a = 'alpha'
>>>> unique_word_b = 'bravo'
>>>> s = 'blah blah alpha i am a good boy bravo blah blah'
>>>> your_string = s[s.find(unique_word_a)+len(unique_word_a):s.find(unique_word_b)].strip()
i am a good boy
```

Comment: what changes do I if I have multiple occurrences of unique word a and unique word b.How do I create an index to search between 5th occurrence of unique word a and unique word b ?