# Find words between two words in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have search end tried alot but i am stuck. I want to get the words between `Ort:` and `Område:` in  a text. This is what i tried last

```
regort = re.compile(r'Ort (.*)(.Område)
```

This works.

```
text = " bla bla Ort: Norra Strö Område: blabla lblalbal"
regort = re.compile(r'Ort: (.*?)Område:')
ort = regort.findall(text)
print ort[0]
Norra Strö
```

Comment: Is this what you meant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222106/how-to-extract-information-between-two-unique-words-in-a-large-text-file

Comment: You missed the colon in your regex.

Comment: regort = re.compile(r'Ort: (.*)(.Område:) 
Still i get some error that it is not ended correctly. I cant find the error in my log right now. I will look for it.

Comment: You aren't closing your raw string and you aren't closing the call to `re.compile()`. You are missing `')` at the end.