# Python read specific lines of text

Tags: python, text, readlines

I am having a problem reading specific lines. It's similar to the question answered here:
[python - Read file from and to specific lines of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559397/python-read-file-from-and-to-specific-lines-of-text)
The difference, I don't have a fixed end mark. Let me show an example:

```
--------------------------------
\n
***** SOMETHING *****     # i use this as my start
\n
--------------------------------
\n
data of interest
data of interest
data of interest
\n
----------------------- #this will either be dashes, or EOF
***** SOMETHING *****
-----------------------
```

I tried doing something similar to the above link, but I can't create a if statement to break the loop since I don't know if it will be the EOF or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
def getBlocks(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        blocks = []
        go = False
        for line in f:
            if line.strip() == startDelimiter:
                block = ''
                go = True
            if go:
                block += line
            if line.strip() == endDelimiter:
                blocks.append(block)
                block = ''
                go = False
        if block:
            blocks.append(block)
    return blocks
```

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but in the event that my file does not have an endDelimiter (i.e. ends at the last data of interest), this wouldn't work.

Comment: You're absolutely right (I knew I forgot something). Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

The beauty is that if you hit EOF, the file will stop iterating.

```
ended = False
for line in f:
    ended = line == MY_END_MARKER
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do

```
parts = my_file.read().split("-----------------------")
print parts
```