# How to start reading from certain line?

Tags: python

I'm unable to solve how can I open file for reading & writing from line 7 and to ignore everything above that line.

```
# Title #
<br />
2013-11-15
<br />
5
6
Random text
```

I did tried the method described here:
[python - Read file from and to specific lines of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559397/python-read-file-from-and-to-specific-lines-of-text)

but it searches for specific match and includes the text above that line. I need the reverse, to include everything starting from line 7.

Comment: just read 6 lines and don't do anything with them?

Comment: I want to read everything starting from line 7 and to ignore all the previous lines [1-6]

Comment: Right. So open the file, read the first six lines and throw them away, and then start whatever you were going to do with the rest.

Comment: I think you misunderstood Mark Reed. How do you mean "ignore"? I guess you want to do something with line 7 after reading it. So you can only read and then ignore lines 1-6, and finally read and do something with line 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will ignore the first 6 lines then print all the lines from the 7th on.

```
with open( file.txt, 'r') as f:
     for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines(), 0):
          if i >= 6:
              print line
```

or as @Paco suggested:

```
with open( file.txt, 'r') as f:
     for line in f.readlines()[6:]:
          print line
```

Comment: you should not have to read all the lines into a list with `readlines`.

Comment: hint : [itertools.islice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

Comment: There is no reason to read the entire file into memory. That is so unPythonic!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

First create a demo file:

```
# create a test file of 'Line X of Y' type
with open('/tmp/lines.txt', 'w') as fout:      
    start,stop=1,11
    for i in range(start,stop):
        fout.write('Line {} of {}\n'.format(i, stop-start))
```

Now work with the file line-by-line:

```
with open('/tmp/lines.txt') as fin:
    # skip first N lines:
    N=7
    garbage=[next(fin) for i in range(N)]   
    for line in fin:
        # do what you are going to do...
```

You can also use [itertools.islice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import itertools        
with open('/tmp/lines.txt') as fin:
    for line in itertools.islice(fin,7,None):
        # there you go with the rest of the file...
```