# Python - Read file and display block of data

Tags: python

I am trying to read file (sample below).
I need to display 2 different set of data

1. first data is not in series (i.e not continuous - spread across text file)

The lines i need to display should have string i am looking for in searchstrings

```
def basic():
    searchstrings = ['Device name:', 'Switch type is', 'Kernel uptime is' , 'NXOS: version' ] 
    for line in fh:
        for word in searchstrings:
            if word in line:
                print line
```

The issue with my above code is multiple lines are getting displayed as shown below:

> NXOS: version 5.2
>    Device name: N11k
>   Kernel uptime is 55 day(s), 23 hour(s), 53 minute(s), 11 second(s)
>    NXOS: version 5.2
>    Device name: N11k
>   Kernel uptime is 55 day(s), 23 hour(s), 53 minute(s), 12 second(s)
>    Switch type is : Nexus1100 (8 Slot) Chassis

I guess my for loop logic is incorrect - need help in fixing it.
Also is it possible to save the line in variable which can be used for printing later ?

2. second data is in series (continuous chunk)
   I want to read from 'show module' till  line above 'show license'
   I tried suggestion listed here - [python - Read file from and to specific lines of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559397/python-read-file-from-and-to-specific-lines-of-text)
   but could not make it to work - i get no output at all

Thanks,
Victor

File which is being read:

> Software
>    BIOS: version 06.20
>    NXOS: version 5.2
>    BIOS compile time:  11/07/2013
>    NXOS image file is: bootflash:///n1000-dk9.5.2.bin
>    NXOS compile time:  6/3/2014 13:00:00 [06/18/2014 23:35:53]
>
> Hardware
>    cisco Nexus1000 C1508 (8 Slot) Chassis ("Supervisor Module")
>    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2403 with 16402460 kB of memory.
>    Processor Board ID SAL
>
> Device name: N1k-LabSystem
>    bootflash:   21 kB
>   Kernel uptime is 55 day(s), 23 hour(s), 53 minute(s), 11 second(s)
>
> Last reset
>    Reason: Unknown
>    System version: 5.2
>    Service:
>
> Switch type is : Nexus1100 (8 Slot) Chassis
>
> `show module`
>   Mod  Ports  Module-Type                           Model            Status
>
> ---
>
> 2    52     48x1/10G SFP+ 4x40G Ethernet Module   N11K-X9564PX      ok
>   3    36     36p 40G Ethernet Module               N11k-X9636PQ      ok
>   21   0      Fabric Module                         N11k-FM     ok
>   22   0      Fabric Module                         N11k-FM     ok
>   23   0      Fabric Module                         N11k-FM     ok
>   24   0      Fabric Module                         N11k-FM     ok
>   25   0      Fabric Module                         N11k-FM     ok
>   26   0      Fabric Module                         N11k-FM     ok
>   27   0      Supervisor Module                     N11k-SUP-A        active *
>   29   0      System Controller                     N11k-SC-A         active
>   30   0      System Controller                     N11k-SC-A         standby
>
> Mod  Sw                Hw     Slot
>
> ---
>
> 2    5.2      1.0    LC2
>   3    5.2      1.0    LC3
>   21   5.2      1.1    FM1
>   22   5.2      1.1    FM2
>
> 'show license'
>   XYZABNCD

Answer (score 0):

The problem is outside of your `basic` function. I tried it and lines are not duplicated. It may only come from the way you call it. If you want to keep them to print later, you should write :

def basic(fh):
    resul = []
    searchstrings = ['Device name:', 'Switch type is', 'Kernel uptime is' , 'NXOS: version' ] 
    for line in fh:
        for word in searchstrings:
            if word in line:
                resul.append(line.strip())
                break
    return resul

That way :

- even if line contained multiple searched words, it would be taken only once
- you pass fh as a parameter instead of using a global
- you return the list of matching lines

To get lines between `show module` and `show license`, you could use :

```
def between(fh, first, last)
    ok = False
    for line in fh:
        if last in line: break
        if ok: print line.rstrip()
        if first in line: ok=True

between('show module', 'show license')
```