# Extract the lines between 2 specific tags

Tags: python, regex

For a routine programming question, I need to extract some lines of text that are between 2 tags(delimiters, if I need to be more specific).

The file is something like this:

```
*some random text*

...

...

...

tag/delimiter 1

text 1   #extract

text 2   #extract

...      #extract

...      #extract

text n   #extract

tag/ending_delimiter

*some random text*


...

...

...
tag/delimiter 2

text 1   #extract

text 2   #extract

...      #extract

...      #extract

text n   #extract

tag/ending_delimiter

*some random text*


...

...

...

tag/delimiter n

text 1   #extract

text 2   #extract

...      #extract

...      #extract

text n   #extract

tag/ending_delimiter

*some random text until the file ends*
```

The ending_delimiter is the same everywhere.

The starting delimiter, i.e delimiter 1, delimiter 2 upto n is taken from a list.

The catch is, in the file there are a few (less than 3) charecters after each starting delimiter, which, combined with the starting delimiter, work as an identifier for the lines of text until the ending_delimiter, a kind of "uid", technically.

So far, what I've tried is this:

```
data_file = open("file_name")
block = []
found = False

for elem in list_of_starting_delimiters:
    for line in data_file:
        if found:
            block.append(line)
            if re.match(attribute_end, line.strip()):
                break
        else:
            if re.match(elem, line.strip()):
                found = True
                block = elem

data_file.close()
```

I have also tried to implement the answers suggested in:

[python - Read file from and to specific lines of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559397/python-read-file-from-and-to-specific-lines-of-text)

but with no success.

The implementation I'm currently trying is one of the answers of the link above.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S: Using Python 2.7, on PyCharm, on Windows 10.

Comment: Note `re.match` only matches at the start of the string. Did you mean that? If not, use `re.search`.

Comment: I really don't know much about using regex, but I'll try `re.search` and get back to you.

Comment: Edit: I did use `re.search` instead of `re.match`, but got an empty list, same as when using `re.match`.

Comment: What  are `lncel_dns` and `attribute_end`?

Comment: `lncel_dns` is the list of starting delimiters, and attribute_end is the common ending delimiter. I'll change the name of the list to something more common          Edit: the list is now '`list_of_starting_delimiters`

Comment: I personally wouldn't put much merit on the linked answer, I can't see where the @WiktorStribiżew saw you mention regex but it is much safer for this application IMO

Comment: Sorry, [still can't make your code work](https://ideone.com/LfWNlB).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please initialize `list_of_starting_delimiters` and put elements as `['tag/delimiter']`. I'm not able to edit the code in https://ideone.com/LfWNlB                                                                               I do have some elements in the list. The elements might be too big to be mentioned here

Comment: What is `attribute_end`?

Comment: The ending delimiter. As mentioned, it is the same throughout the file. For now, put `attribute_end = tag/ending_delimiter`

Comment: You have  `block = elem` while it should be `block.append(elem)`, see https://ideone.com/LfWNlB

Comment: I think https://ideone.com/RJBeEq will be the fix.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your code is only extracting the text within `tag/delimiter 1` and `tag/ending_delimiter`. It did not extract the other lines of text that also need to be extracted.

Comment: If you see https://ideone.com/RJBeEq, you will see all three blocks extracted.

Comment: It'll take some work to integrate it into my code, but you made the base code work. [https://ideone.com/RJBeEq](This) will probably be the one that fixes my code. Thanks! I'll try the fixes in the answers as well. Cheers!

Comment: The answers below all imply you need to read the whole file into memory.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good point, should be checked if important depending on filesize. However, if processed line by line, you wouldn't need `re` anymore, would you?

Comment: @SpghttCd That is what I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew correct, sorry - I was just aware that you talked with OP via some online coding page and without really thinking associated it with an online regex tester. However, I can imagine it could be done even a little shorter, especially if tags fill a whole line... I'll try to test if I find some time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest fixing your code the following way:

```
block = []
found = False
list_of_starting_delimiters = ['tag/delimiter']
attribute_end = 'tag/ending_delimiter'
curr = []

for elem in list_of_starting_delimiters:
    for line in data_file:
        if found:
            curr.append(line)
            if line.strip().startswith(attribute_end):
                found = False
                block.append("\n".join(curr))            # Add merged list to final list
                curr = []                                # Zero out current list
        else: 
            if line.strip().startswith(elem):            # If line starts with start delimiter
                found = True
                curr.append(line.strip())                # Append line to current list 

if len(curr) > 0:      # If there are still lines in the current list
    block.append(curr) # Add them to the final list
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RJBeEq)

There are quite a lot of issues with your current code:

- `block = elem` made `block` a byte string and the further `.append` caused an exception
- You only grabbed one occurrence of the block because upon fining one, you had a `break` statement
- All the lines were added as separate items while you needed to collect them into a list and then join them with `\n` to get strings to paste into a resulting list
- You need no regex to check if a string appears at the start of a string, use `str.startswith` method.

Comment: A drawback of this solution from my point of view is, that for n sections to extract it iterates n times over the whole file.

Comment: @SpghttCd If the delimiters are overlapping, it is still the most efficient solution. Regex like `(?=(...))` will be an overkill if the file is huge.

Comment: I do not speak of regex (anymore, see my latest answer below, it iterates only once through the file). Besides, I don't understand what you mean by overlapping delimiters

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
import re

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()

losd = '|'.join(list_of_starting_delimiters)
enddel = 'attribute_end'
block = re.findall('(?:' + losd + r')([\s\S]*?)' + enddel, txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

By the time I figured this out there are a fair amount of good responses already, but my approach would be that you could resolve this with:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"(^tag\/delimiter) (.{0,3})\n\n((^[\w\d #\.]*$\n)+)^(tag\/ending_delimiter)", re.M)
```

You could then find all matches in your text by either doing:

```
 for i in pattern.finditer(<target_text>):
    #do something with each match

 pattern.findAll(<target_text>) - returns a list of strings of all matches
```

This of course bears the stipulation that you need to specify different delimiters and compile a different regex pattern (re.compile) for each different delimiter, using variables and string concatenation as @SpghttCd shows in his answer

For more info see the python [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would make that in following way: For example purpose let `<d1>` and `<d2>` and `<d3>` be our starting delimiters and `<d>` ending delimeter and `string` being text you are processing. Then following line of code:

`re.findall('(<d1>|<d2>|<d3>)(.+?)(<d>)',string,re.DOTALL)`

will give list of tuples, with each tuple containing starting delimiter, body and ending delimiter. This code use grouping inside regular expression (brackets), pipe (|) in regular expressions acts similar to or, dot (.) combined with DOTALL flag match any character, plus (+) means 1 or more, question (?) non-greedy manner (this is important in this case, as otherwise you would get single match begining at first starting delimiter and ending at last ending delimiter)

Answer (score 0):

My `re`-less solution would be the following:

```
list_of_starting_delimiters = ['tag/delimiter 1', 'tag/delimiter 2', 'tag/delimiter n']
enddel = 'tag/ending_delimiter'

block ={}
section = ''
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == enddel:
            section = ''
        if section:
            block[section] = block.get(section, '') + line
        if line.strip() in list_of_starting_delimiters:
            section = line.strip()

print(block)
```

It extracts the blocks into a dictionary with start delimiter tags as keys and according sections as values.
It requires the start and end tags to be the only content of their respective lines.

Output:

```
{'tag/delimiter 1':
'\ntext 1   #extract\n\ntext 2   #extract\n\n...      #extract\n\n...      #extract\n\ntext n   #extract\n\n', 
'tag/delimiter 2':
'\ntext 1   #extract\n\ntext 2   #extract\n\n...      #extract\n\n...      #extract\n\ntext n   #extract\n\n', 
'tag/delimiter n':
'\ntext 1   #extract\n\ntext 2   #extract\n\n...      #extract\n\n...      #extract\n\ntext n   #extract\n\n'}
```